# IServiceCollection.AddHostedService<>(); does not resolve

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection

I have a strange occurrence happening in a brand new .net core 2 web app. This is the standard web api from the template built into Visual Studio. VS 2017, all the jazz. Here's the the entire startup.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using VerySimpleAPI.Helpers;

namespace VerySimpleAPI
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddHostedService<MainLoop>();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseMvc(routes => {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "Default",
                    template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index"}
                    );
            });
        }
    }
}
```

`MainLoop` implements `IHostedService` and `IDisposable`.

The `services.AddHostedService<MainLoop>();` does not resolve, producing the error "'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddHostedService' and no extension method..." all that jazz. I checked out the `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` source, and I clearly see the definition for `public static IServiceCollection AddHostedService<THostedService>(this IServiceCollection services)`

Without the hosted service reference, the project compiles just fine. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: `AddHostedService` is part of `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions`. While it is defined in the `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` namespace, it belongs to  `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions` in the [`ServiceCollectionHostedServiceExtensions`](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions/ServiceCollectionHostedServiceExtensions.cs) class

Comment: @Nkosi adding `using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;` and `using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions;` does nothing. I can clearly see the the definition for AddHostedService here: https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions/ServiceCollectionHostedServiceExtensions.cs

Comment: Yep exactly the same source I linked to.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`AddHostedService` is part of `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions`.

While it is defined in the `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` namespace, it belongs to  `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions` in the [`ServiceCollectionHostedServiceExtensions`](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/master/src/Hosting/Abstractions/src/ServiceCollectionHostedServiceExtensions.cs) class

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Extensions;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
{
    public static class ServiceCollectionHostedServiceExtensions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Add an <see cref="IHostedService"/> registration for the given type.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="THostedService">An <see cref="IHostedService"/> to register.</typeparam>
        /// <param name="services">The <see cref="IServiceCollection"/> to register with.</param>
        /// <returns>The original <see cref="IServiceCollection"/>.</returns>
        public static IServiceCollection AddHostedService<THostedService>(this IServiceCollection services)
            where THostedService : class, IHostedService
        {
            services.TryAddEnumerable(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<IHostedService, THostedService>());

            return services;
        }
    }
}
```

And ensure that the relevant packages are installed and referenced to have access to the extension method

Comment: Good find, I'm glad you showed the source, I could of sworn hosted services were added as singletons +1

Comment: This is the source I originally turned to, when encountered that problem. `using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;` does nothing. There's something else missing.

Comment: @Nomenator Are you referencing the necessary libraries?

Comment: @Nkosi Good question. Apparently, Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting and Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions were not installed as nuget packages. I assumed they were available, since `using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting` did not complain about not having a definition. Apparently, now we can use packages which are not installed. I had to drop `using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting` because `'IHostingEnvironment' is an ambiguous reference between 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment' and 'Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment``

Comment: @Nomenator, Have you resolved the issue? I have the same problem. I am on core 2.0. Interesting to note, ServiceCollectionHostedServiceExtensions.AddHostedService is applied to .NET Platform Extensions
3.1 3.0 2.2 2.1 only.  It seems like it is not available in  2.0.

Comment: @armyllc While the extension may not exist in that version, you can still manually add the hosted service

Comment: @armyllc are you able to upgrade to v2.1

Comment: @armyllc Yes, the issue was resolved with Nkosi's answer. It describes exactly which packages are needed and how they interact with the involved dependencies.

Comment: In Core 6.0, it appears to be `using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` which is required. The really odd thing is that `dotnet new worker` creates a template with no `using`s, and seems to work. But once I started making changes I got errors without `using` for both **DependencyInjection** and **Hosting**

Comment: Ah, never mind my last comment. The `using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` is probably still right, but `dotnet new worker` makes it implicit via `<ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>` in the .csproj.